# How to center a card in semantic-ui?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have implemented owl slider for cards, I tried to simulate as mobile device, it looks the card is not properly centered.

[image]

I've tried all UI grid and other center classes, they didn't work.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel">

    <div class="ui card">
        <div class="image dimmable">
            <div class="ui blurring inverted dimmer transition hidden">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="center">
                       <div class="ui teal button">Ver más sobre Circulo K</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="../assets/images/stores/circulok.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">Circulo K</div>
                <div class="meta">
                    <a class="group">Meta</a>
                </div>
                <div class="description">Descripción Corta</div>
            </div>

            <div class="extra content">
                <a class="right floated created">Arbitrary</a>
                <a class="friends"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

How do I that?

Comment: a fiddle would be useful, your html is pretty unreadably formatted btw, I dont really understand if your goal is for the card to be in the middle or the content of the card, if it's the card, just position it as it would be any other div, not really a semantic issue at all...

Comment: Hi @mikus I think I already solved it, this question has been 2 weeks ago there no point to answer this question.

The workaround was using class ui.container.center.aligned or ui.grid.centered.

Comment: @ivan go ahead and answer it with that. It's ok to answer your own questions.

Comment: good its solved now, often you can also simply override whatever semantic defines, just use !important (not recommended) or very specific css selector. Also sometimes its not as invasice and simple css solves the problem too. Of course using defined elements is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using class such as ui grid centered or ui container center aligned

For example:

```
<div class="ui container center aligned">
  <div class="ui segment">Hello Center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the **centered** class.

```html
<div class="ui centered card"><br> <!-- HERE -->
<div class="image">
    <img src="/path/to/image/"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="header">Link</a><br>
  </div>
</div>
```